# Python: Try, Continue, Except statement in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, continue, except

I literally just learned about the concept of working around errors encountered in for-loops. I have a list of files read in from my local computer and I'd like to read them in as pandas dataframes.

Let's say I have a list of files and each file as columns "A", "B" and "C".
If there is a specific column, lets say column "B" from file3.tbl, missing from a file on my computer, I want to continue with my for loop.

```
list = ['file1.tbl', 'file2.tbl', 'file3.tbl']
for i in range(len(list)):
    data = pandas.read_csv(list[i])
    try:
        b = data['B']
        continue
    except Exception:
        print "Column B not included in file: ", list[i]
```

This seems to work somewhat but it prints the except statment len(list) number of times, like so:

```
Column B not included in file: file3.tbl
Column B not included in file: file3.tbl
Column B not included in file: file3.tbl
```

Is there a way to get it to print only one time for that specific iteration?

Comment: Do you mean `list[i]` instead of `list[ii]`? Also, the indentation is off on your `try` block.

Comment: Yes, I do! I'll edit both of those.

Comment: Don’t do `except Exception`; it has the potential to hide a bunch of things you would rather know about. `except KeyError` would be more specific. Also, are you sure this is actually your code? It’s strange for `.dat` to be printed when your list only contains `.tbl`.

Comment: A couple style pointers: don't use builtin names (such as `list`) for your variables.  Use a meaningful name such as `files` or `filenames`.  Also, it's better to loop over the items in such a list directly with `for file in files:` instead of looping over the list indexes.

Comment: I think @Ryan nailed it -- your error message refers to `file3.dat`, but your code defines `file3.tbl`.  This isn't the actual code you're running.

Comment: Sorry! I'm thinking of too many different file types and typed the wrong outputs. I fixed it! Thank you for the suggestion of KeyError Ryan, I think that is probably what I should use instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, you likely have namespace issue.  Here's some cleaned up code that should print uniquely for each `Exception`.  It includes the Pythonic suggestions that agree with the comments.

For three csv-like files `"file1.tbl", "file2.tbl", "file3.tbl"`, I get the following:

```
import pandas as pd


filenames = ["file1.tbl", "file2.tbl", "file3.tbl"]        # @John Gordon
for fn in filenames:
    data = pd.read_csv(fn)
    try: 
        b = data['B']
    except (KeyError):                                     # @Ryan
        print("Column B not included in file: ", fn)
    else:
        # Do something with b (optional)
        pass


# Column B not included in file:  file1.tbl
# Column B not included in file:  file2.tbl
# Column B not included in file:  file3.tbl
```

Comment: Hi pylang, thanks for nicely summing up the suggestions. Would the else statement continue the except part of the logic or would it pick up where the try statement left off? Or would it start at the beginning of the loop?

Comment: @DaxFeliz: The else statement will be executed only if no exceptions occur.

Comment: It continues from the `try` block in the absence of an exception, as @Arun mentioned.

Comment: Logically, this makes sense to me but this version still prints the except message multiple times.

Comment: I ran the code on `.tbl` files (?) and get the results in the updated post.  Try a fresh Python session.  Then try new files.